# No response, while connecting to the database

Tags: h2

I am using H2 for a Java Swing desktop application.

I cannot able to connect to the database, only in the server mode.

URL is : jdbc:h2:tcp://115.241.34.158:9092/Lion/Companies/1(2012-2013)/1(2012-2013);DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=5;IFEXISTS=TRUE

The system, simply hangs, while giving java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

Not throwing any exception (or) any messages.

It works fine, in single user mode. (without server)

What will be the possible solution ?. Please advice.

Thanks and regards,

I.Murugesan

Comment: Where exactly do you want the database file to be stored (absolute directory)? How did you start the server?

Comment: I am storing the database file in System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+dbFolderName+"/"+dbName. Our software has two databases namely "UserDB" and "CompanyDB" respectively. Both databases required to be started for the application. First the "UserDB" will be started and from that "CompanyDB" will be started. We are starting the server during connecting "UserDB" itself. "UserDB" Database connected well. The problem is only while connecting "CompanyDB". Please help.

Comment: Could you post the code used to start the H2 TCP server?

Comment: if (server != null) {
try {
if (server.isRunning(true)) {
return;
}
server.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
} else {
try {
server = Server.createTcpServer(new String[]{"-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers"});
server.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
}

Comment: Hi Thomas, 
Shall I  use same port (default port 9092) for both UserDB and CompanyDB to start ? Because, earlier I have used the default port for both DBs. Now, after changing different port ids for each databases and starting two servers for each databases, CompanyDB connects and runs. 
Is it necessary to run two servers for two databases ?
Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One TCP server can be used for multiple databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the TCP server without base directory, then you should use a different database URL. The following database URL

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://115.241.34.158:9092/~/Lion/Companies
```

means the database file `Companies.h2.db` is stored in the directory `Lion` *within the current user home directory*. But if you use

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://115.241.34.158:9092/Lion/Companies/1(2012-2013)/1(2012-2013)
```

then the database file `1(2012-2013).h2.db` is stored in the directory `Lion/Companies/1(2012-2013)` relative to the *current working directory*. And the working directory depends on where you have started the TCP server.

Comment: Thanks for your information. 
Yes, That is how we have. 
Please clarify, whether we have to start separate servers for each database ? Shall we start server once, and establish connection for the two databases with the same port ?

Comment: One server can server multiple databases. If possible, only one server should be started. There is one port per server.

Comment: Still, I cannot able to connect to my company database. Not responding after DriverManager.getConnection(). Please suggest me, how to proceed further.

Comment: Could you get a full thread dump? Also, could you post a reproducible test case?